# Conditionally style not working in react native

Tags: react-native

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478621/react-native-styling-with-conditional) answer to dynamically style my component.

Here is my render method :

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.images}
          numColumns={2}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
          keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
          keyExtractor={item => item.localIdentifier}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) =>

            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor='transparent'
              onPress={() => this.openImage(index)}
              onLongPress={() => this.startSelection(item)}
            >
              <View style={[styles.albumContainer, (this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1)?styles.selectedItem:styles.unselectedItem]}>
                <Image
                  style={styles.albumThumbnail}
                  source={item.image}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

As you can see I am displaying image thumbnail with `TouchableHighlight` and `FlatList`. When user will press and hold on any image thumbnail I called `startSelection()` with particular flatlist item which then add that item to state. I used that state to set style dynamically of my image as :

```html
<View style={[styles.albumContainer, (this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1)?styles.selectedItem:styles.unselectedItem]}>
    <Image
        style={styles.albumThumbnail}
        source={item.image}
    />
</View>
```

Here is `startSelection()` method :

```js
  startSelection(item) {
    let temp = this.state.selectedItems;
    temp.push(item);
    this.setState({
      selectedItems : temp
    });
  }
```

Here is my stylesheet :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  selectedItem: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: '#22aaff',
  },
  unselectedItem: {
    borderColor: '#000000',
  }
});
```

But when user press and hold that view, item will added to state but style is not changing.
Please help me what's going wrong here !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be found on FlatList [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist):

> This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if props remain shallow-equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem function depends on is passed as a prop (e.g. extraData) that is not === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data prop and parent component state.

So you can add extraData to your FlatList component like this:

1. FlatList Component:

   ```
   <FlatList
     data={this.state.images}
     extraData={this.state} //add this!
     numColumns={2}
     keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
     keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
     keyExtractor={item => item.localIdentifier}
     renderItem={({ item, index }) =>

       <TouchableHighlight
         underlayColor='transparent'
         onPress={() => this.openImage(index)}
         onLongPress={() => this.startSelection(item)}
       >
         <View style={[styles.albumContainer, (this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1)?styles.selectedItem:styles.unselectedItem]}>
           <Image
             style={styles.albumThumbnail}
             source={item.image}
           />
         </View>
       </TouchableHighlight>
     }
   />
   ```

P.S: If your component state has variables which should not re-render FlatList, you would be better of using `extraData = {this.state.selectedItems}`, but then you need to make sure you pass a different reference to selectedItems when you call setState on startSelection. Like this:

```
startSelection(item) {
  let temp = [...this.state.selectedItems];
  temp.push(item);
  this.setState({
    selectedItems : temp
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them with extra `[]`

```
style={[styles.albumContainer, [(this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1)?styles.selectedItem:styles.unselectedItem]]}
```